# React - How do you force an onLoad call for image

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing a React component and having trouble with getting an image reload bypassing the cache. I have Googled other solutions and know that if I bring the `onLoad` attribute up before the `src` attribute that it "should" work but it does not appear to do so.

Here is my code:

```
export class ImageComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
             <div>
                 <img 
                     onLoad={() => this.props.calculateImageMargin(this.imageRef)}
                     src={"./myImage.jpg"}
                     ref={(ref) => this.imageRef = ref}
                     onClick={() => this.props.openFullScreen()}
                 />
             </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This image is used in this way: I can click on the image which opens it up to a full screen and then I can rotate it.  When I save those changes, a thumbnail image should show it in the rotated state. However, `calculateImageMargin` is called when I manually refresh the page but is not called when I save the rotated image. How do I get the image to call `onLoad` in that case?  I have tried moving `onLoad` up before `src` but that does not seem to work.

**EDIT**

I have moved the `onLoad` callback to a `componentDidMount` instead.

```
export class ImageComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.imageRef = null;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.calculateImageMargin(this.imageRef);
    }

    render() {
        return (
             <div>
                 <img 
                     src={"./myImage.jpg"}
                     ref={(ref) => this.imageRef = ref}
                     onClick={() => this.props.openFullScreen()}
                 />
             </div>
        );
    }
}
```

When I set some console logs throughout, it appears that the `imageRef` is set by the `img` tag first, then the `componentDidMount` fires. However, the proper image height and width does not appear to be coming through appropriately. In addition, I am not sure if this solution will set the `img` margin appropriately after I modify it in my `calculateImageMargin` function.

I also tried putting the `calculateImageMargin` function in the `render()` body but get `undefined` errors because `imageRef` is not set at that point.

Comment: have you tried to solve margin by only css?

Answer (score 0):

Either there's not enough code here, or this is working as expected. The image isn't being reloaded. It's just being rotated. What you might want is something like move the `onLoad` callback to the render method's body, so that when you rotate the component, and it re-renders, the `ImageMargin` is recalculated.

Comment: How would I access `this.imageRef` though? I have also considered doing a `componentWillMount` or a `componentDidMount` but can't figure out how to get the `imageRef` to pass through.